# Moving focus from one control to next control with imeOptions with Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have problem implementing the scanrios below with the code below

I have a UI with two EditTexts, one checkbox, and a submit button.

Scenario 1:

`Time` EditText: Its click event opens up a TimePicker. When TimePicker gets a value and closes, the focus moves to `Containers` EditText.

The **problem**: the focus is still on `Time` EditText

`Containers` EditText: when a value is entered, and click finish, the focus moves to `Submit` button.

The **problem**: the focus is still on `Containers` EditText

Scanario 2:
`Cancel` checkbox: when checked, the focus moves to `Submit` button.

The **problem**: the focus is still on `Cancel` checkbox

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_timepicker"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none|time"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Containers"

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_containers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancelled"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_cancelled"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:imeOptions="normal|actionDone" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">     
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="normal|actionSend" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I test the code you provided, but can not reproduce. Could you provide the xaml with code behind for me to test?